# java Gson.fromJson loses information

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a json result I got from a website.

```
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

in the content String I see a specific data that I need.
when I use Gson to return the object this data disappears:

```
return new Gson().fromJson(content, clazz);
```

most of the data does not disappears.
any idea to why and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Show your class and sample json. It might be the problem of mapping json to field probably having different name convention

Comment: the problem was that I didn't supply all post params it needed so the post wasn't initiated.